# Visual issue when closing "This post has been deleted" message

Tags: bug, design

I was going through the one review queue, and was trying to edit the one post I came across. While I was working on it, the user deleted their post. I was provided with the appropriate notification that I could no longer edit the post.

[image: "No more edits" message]

But when I clicked on the x at the right to close that message, the header did not go back up to the top of the page as it should, and stayed at its position (two down for some reason) until I refreshed the entire page.

[image: Big gap left on page]

**UPDATE**

I was trying to edit a post when it got approved just now, and was going to follow Dan Neely's suggestion from the comments and shrink my browser before taking the screenshots. When I did that, the Title bar moved back to the top of the page, and didn't follow the above screenshots.

Comment: The X is all the way over to the right of the screen. I just shrank down my screenshots some to save space and keep them visible since I have a 22" monitor, it would have been very large.

Comment: @krillgar In the future, showing all of the problem in a screenshot is preferable to cropping part of the problem out to make it look better when squeezed into a narrow width.  If you're concerned about your native width causing legibility problems in a question/answer the better option is to resize your browser window to make it narrower prior to taking a screenshot.  (As a precautionary measure, I'd take a full width one first just in case the browser resize triggers a page refresh that hides/fixes the issue.)

Comment: OK, I get what you're saying. However I didn't feel that the width of the browser had anything to do with the fact that the contents of the page stay the height of that notification below `window.top`. If I come across it again, I'll retake new screenshots.